# request.on in http.createServer(function(request,response) {});

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

```
var http = require('http');

var map = require('through2-map');

uc = map(function(ch) {    
  return ch.toString().toUpperCase();  
});

server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.on('data',function(chunk){
      if (request.method == 'POST') {
         //change the data from request to uppercase letters and 
         //pipe to response. 
      }
    });
});
server.listen(8000);
```

I have two questions about the code above. First, I read the documentation for request, it said that request is an instance of IncomingMessage, which implements Readable Stream. However, I couldn't find .on method in the Stream documentation. So I don't know what chunk in the callback function in request.on does. Secondly, I want to do some manipulation to the data from request and pipe it to response. Should I pipe from chunk or from request? Thank you for consideration!

Comment: About `However, I couldn't find .on method in the Stream documentation.` It is because Stream implements EventEmitter (doc says `All streams are EventEmitters`). you have to check at https://nodejs.org/api/events.html for this specific methods. Otherwise i did not understand clearly your queston. Basically you should pipe the request stream into the response stream. Streams are made of chunk of data written from one end to another.

Comment: is chunk a stream? Also, whenever someone sends a request to this server would that entire thing be a chunk? If two people send two requests would that be two chunks?

Answer (score 0):

All Streams are instances of `EventEmitter` ([docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/events.html)), that is where the `.on` method comes from.

Regarding the second question, you MUST pipe from the Stream object (`request` in this case). The `"data"` event emits data as a `Buffer` or a `String` (the `"chunk"` argument in the event listener), not a stream.

Manipulating Streams is usually done by implementing a `Transform` stream ([docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_transform_1)). Though there are many NPM packages available that make this process simpler (like `through2-map` or the like), though in reality, they produce `Transform` streams.

Consider the following:

```
    var http = require('http');

    var map = require('through2-map');

    // Transform Stream to uppercase
    var uc = map(function(ch) {    
      return ch.toString().toUpperCase();  
    });

    var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      // Pipe from the request to our transform stream
      request
        .pipe(uc)
        // pipe from transfrom stream to response
        .pipe(response);
    });
    server.listen(8000);
```

You can test by running curl:

```
$ curl -X POST -d 'foo=bar' http://localhost:8000
# logs FOO=BAR
```

Answer (score 0):

> is chunk a stream?

nop. The stream is the flow among what the chunks of the whole data are sent.
A simple example, If you read a 1gb file, a stream will read it by chunks of 10k, each chunk will go through your stream, from the beginning to the end, with the right order.
I use a file as example, but a socket, request or whatever streams is based on that idea.

> Also, whenever someone sends a request to this server would that entire thing be a chunk?

In the particular case of http requests, only the request body is a stream. It can be the posted files/data. Or the response body of the response. Headers are treated as Objects to apply on the request before the body is written on the socket.

A small example to help you with some concrete code,

```
var through2 = require('through2');

var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var s1 = through2(function transform(chunk, enc, cb){
  console.log("s1 chunk %s", chunk.toString())
  cb(err=null, chunk.toString()+chunk.toString() )
});

var s2 = through2(function transform(chunk, enc, cb){
  console.log("s2 chunk %s", chunk.toString())
  cb(err=null, chunk)
});

s2.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("s2 data %s", data.toString())
})

s1.on('end', function (data) {
  console.log("s1 end")
})

s2.on('end', function (data) {
  console.log("s2 end")
})

var rs = new Readable;
rs.push('beep '); // this is a chunk
rs.push('boop'); // this is a chunk
rs.push(null); // this is a signal to end the stream

rs.on('end', function (data) {
  console.log("rs end")
})

console.log(
  ".pipe always return piped stream: %s", rs.pipe(s1)===s1
)

s1.pipe(s2)
```

---

I would like to suggest you to read more :

- https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook
- http://maxogden.com/node-streams.html
- https://github.com/maxogden/mississippi